# How to "pretty" format JSON output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, pretty-print

I would like my JSON output in Ruby on Rails to be "pretty" or nicely formatted.

Right now, I call `to_json` and my JSON is all on one line.  At times this can be difficult to see if there is a problem in the JSON output stream.

Is there way to configure to make my JSON "pretty" or nicely formatted in Rails?

Comment: Not sure where you're looking at it, but in webkit's console it creates a nice tree out of any JSON logged or requested.

Comment: One thing to remember when doing this, is that your JSON content's size will balloon because of the additional whitespace. In a development environment it is often helpful to have the JSON easy to read, but in a production environment you want your content to be as lean as you can get it for speed and responsiveness in the user's browser.

Comment: use `y my_json` will nicely format stuff if you wanna some quick fix.

Comment: @randomor `undefined method 'y' for main:Object`

Comment: `y` is available in rails console.

Comment: `y` prints out YAML formatting (which is always pretty); `j` prints out JSON formatting, but not prettified. [TheDeadSerious's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails#comment4599397_1823885) shows you how you can get pretty printouts instead.

Answer (score 1161, accepted):

Use the `pretty_generate()` function, built into later versions of JSON. For example:

```
require 'json'
my_object = { :array => [1, 2, 3, { :sample => "hash"} ], :foo => "bar" }
puts JSON.pretty_generate(my_object)
```

Which gets you:

```
{
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    {
      "sample": "hash"
    }
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: Nifty! I've put this into my ~/.irbrc:
def json_pp(json)
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(json))
end

Comment: To make this useful in Rails, it seems that you should give an answer which includes code that can be used in the same context as `format.json { render :json => @whatever }`

Comment: Surely prettyprinting should only be used for server-side debugging?  If you stick the code above in a controller, you'll have tons of useless whitespace in all responses, which isn't even needed for client-side debugging as any tools worth their salt (eg. Firebug) already handle prettyprinting JSON.

Comment: @jpatokal: you may consider there to be other better options, but the question was how to get this to work in Rails.  Saying "you don't want to do that in Rails" is a non-answer.  Obviously a lot of people want to do it in Rails.

Comment: The original poster said nothing about _where_ in a Rails app he wants to use this, so I answered with a line of Ruby that will work anywhere.  To use it to generate the JSON response in a Rails *controller*, you already answered your own question: `format.json { render :json => JSON.pretty_generate(my_json) }`.

Comment: @jpatokal's comment above for `render` didn't work for me. I had to modify it a bit: `render :json => JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(my_json))`

Comment: If you have to call `JSON.parse` on it, your `my_json` is a string, not JSON!

Comment: There is also handy method in console `jj`, which pretty prints json object to STDOUT

Comment: Is there a better way to do something like `JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(json_stuff))` if you have a json and not a hash?

Answer (score 113):

The `<pre>` tag in HTML, used with `JSON.pretty_generate`, will render the JSON pretty in your view. I was so happy when my illustrious boss showed me this:

```
<% if @data.present? %>
   <pre><%= JSON.pretty_generate(@data) %></pre>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 82):

Thanks to Rack Middleware and Rails 3 you can output pretty JSON for every request without changing any controller of your app. I have written such middleware snippet and I get nicely printed JSON in browser and `curl` output.

```
class PrettyJsonResponse
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    if headers["Content-Type"] =~ /^application\/json/
      obj = JSON.parse(response.body)
      pretty_str = JSON.pretty_unparse(obj)
      response = [pretty_str]
      headers["Content-Length"] = pretty_str.bytesize.to_s
    end
    [status, headers, response]
  end
end
```

The above code should be placed in `app/middleware/pretty_json_response.rb` of your Rails project.
And the final step is to register the middleware in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use PrettyJsonResponse
```

**I don't recommend to use it in `production.rb`**. The JSON reparsing may degrade response time and throughput of your production app. Eventually extra logic such as 'X-Pretty-Json: true' header may be introduced to trigger formatting for manual curl requests on demand.

(Tested with Rails 3.2.8-5.0.0, Ruby 1.9.3-2.2.0, Linux)

Comment: How are you getting around ActiveSupport's [redefinition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb) of to_json?  This keeps me from pretty printing while ActiveSupport is present.

Comment: I don't care really, to_json, as_json, [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) which I use mostly - whatever, middleware transforms any JSON output. I try to avoid opening classes whenever possible.

Comment: I had to change the parse line to `obj = JSON.parse(response.body.first)` to make it work.

Comment: Just tried your advice and it failed as `body` is a string under both Thin and Passenger in development mode. RoR3/4 and Ruby 2.0. The `response.body` is http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionDispatch/Response/body

Comment: Works great in Rails 4 as well... thanks! I prefer this to the more library-specific methods (as in the accepted answer). Since you should only use this in dev mode anyways, the performance hit isn't a big deal.

Comment: I like this one, and I am looking forward to using it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26491790/238886 for an evolution of this solution that does not call `response.body` and should work in any Rack app.

Comment: Working wonderfully for me with rails 4.2.5 and Puma as my server. Absolutely lovely. Thank you!

Comment: In Rails 5 I had to change `Rack::Utils.bytesize(pretty_str).to_s` to `pretty_str.bytesize.to_s` and it works great!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!  I made a gem out of this: https://github.com/zeiv/rails_pretty_json

Answer (score 27):

Check out [Awesome Print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print).  Parse the JSON string into a Ruby Hash, then display it with `ap` like so:

```
require "awesome_print"
require "json"

json = '{"holy": ["nested", "json"], "batman!": {"a": 1, "b": 2}}'

ap(JSON.parse(json))
```

With the above, you'll see:

```
{
  "holy" => [
    [0] "nested",
    [1] "json"
  ],
  "batman!" => {
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2
  }
}
```

Awesome Print will also add some color that Stack Overflow won't show you.

Comment: This one is really good and makes the results easier to read. It shows the results in different colors and is great for Active-record, hash or array...

Answer (score 26):

If you want to:

1. Prettify all outgoing JSON responses from your app automatically.
2. Avoid polluting Object#to_json/#as_json
3. Avoid parsing/re-rendering JSON using middleware (YUCK!)
4. Do it the RAILS WAY!

Then ... replace the ActionController::Renderer for JSON! Just add the following code to your ApplicationController:

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :json do |json, options|
  unless json.kind_of?(String)
    json = json.as_json(options) if json.respond_to?(:as_json)
    json = JSON.pretty_generate(json, options)
  end

  if options[:callback].present?
    self.content_type ||= Mime::JS
    "#{options[:callback]}(#{json})"
  else
    self.content_type ||= Mime::JSON
    json
  end
end
```

Comment: This is awesome, but it actually causes dates/times to render differently:
https://gist.github.com/nornagon/9c24b68bd6d3e871add3

Comment: Several problems with this: (1) JSON.pretty_generate requires `json.respond_to?(:to_h)` or `:to_hash`. (2) pretty_generate can choke on things that to_json does not.

Comment: @nornagon I haven't applied this change and I'm getting the same difference you saw between .to_json and pretty_generate. I only see it in a rails console, not plain irb. I think this could be a general rails thing, nothing to do with this patch. Also, Time.parse returns the same result when you convert the string back to time for both formats. It'd only be a minor inconvenience when searching logs for time stamps, but if you're grepping anyway adding a few \s+ isn't really a big deal.

Comment: @nornagon looks like the issue you saw was ActiveSupport's [redefinition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb) of to_json, as mentioned in [Ammo Goettsch's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029297/6305204)

Answer (score 19):

If you  find that the `pretty_generate` option built into Ruby's JSON library is not "pretty" enough, I recommend my own [NeatJSON](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON) gem for your formatting.

To use it:

```
gem install neatjson
```

and then use

```
JSON.neat_generate
```

instead of

```
JSON.pretty_generate
```

Like Ruby's `pp` it will keep objects and arrays on one line when they fit, but wrap to multiple as needed. For example:

```json
{
  "navigation.createroute.poi":[
    {"text":"Lay in a course to the Hilton","params":{"poi":"Hilton"}},
    {"text":"Take me to the airport","params":{"poi":"airport"}},
    {"text":"Let's go to IHOP","params":{"poi":"IHOP"}},
    {"text":"Show me how to get to The Med","params":{"poi":"The Med"}},
    {"text":"Create a route to Arby's","params":{"poi":"Arby's"}},
    {
      "text":"Go to the Hilton by the Airport",
      "params":{"poi":"Hilton","location":"Airport"}
    },
    {
      "text":"Take me to the Fry's in Fresno",
      "params":{"poi":"Fry's","location":"Fresno"}
    }
  ],
  "navigation.eta":[
    {"text":"When will we get there?"},
    {"text":"When will I arrive?"},
    {"text":"What time will I get to the destination?"},
    {"text":"What time will I reach the destination?"},
    {"text":"What time will it be when I arrive?"}
  ]
}
```

It also supports a variety of [formatting options](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON#options) to further customize your output. For example, how many spaces before/after colons? Before/after commas? Inside the brackets of arrays and objects? Do you want to sort the keys of your object? Do you want the colons to all be lined up?

Answer (score 19):

Using `<pre>` HTML code and `pretty_generate` is good trick:

```
<%
  require 'json'

  hash = JSON[{hey: "test", num: [{one: 1, two: 2, threes: [{three: 3, tthree: 33}]}]}.to_json] 
%>

<pre>
  <%=  JSON.pretty_generate(hash) %>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 17):

Dumping an ActiveRecord object to JSON (in the Rails console):

```
pp User.first.as_json

# => {
 "id" => 1,
 "first_name" => "Polar",
 "last_name" => "Bear"
}
```

Comment: to get a string from `pp` instead of printing to standard output, use `User.first.as_json.pretty_inspect`.  Works well for me.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a middleware solution modified from [this excellent answer by @gertas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029297/238886).  This solution is not Rails specific--it should work with any Rack application.

The middleware technique used here, using #each, is explained at [ASCIIcasts 151: Rack Middleware](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) by Eifion Bedford.

This code goes in *app/middleware/pretty_json_response.rb*:

```
class PrettyJsonResponse

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    [@status, @headers, self]
  end

  def each(&block)
    @response.each do |body|
      if @headers["Content-Type"] =~ /^application\/json/
        body = pretty_print(body)
      end
      block.call(body)
    end
  end

  private

  def pretty_print(json)
    obj = JSON.parse(json)  
    JSON.pretty_unparse(obj)
  end

end
```

To turn it on, add this to config/environments/test.rb and config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.middleware.use "PrettyJsonResponse"
```

As @gertas warns in his version of this solution, avoid using it in production.  It's somewhat slow.

Tested with Rails 4.1.6.

Answer (score 7):

```
#At Controller
def branch
    @data = Model.all
    render json: JSON.pretty_generate(@data.as_json)
end
```

Answer (score 7):

#### if you want to handle active_record object, `puts` is enough.

for example:

- without `puts`

```rb
2.6.0 (main):0 > User.first.to_json
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "{\"id\":1,\"admin\":true,\"email\":\"admin@gmail.com\",\"password_digest\":\"$2a$10$TQy3P7NT8KrdCzliNUsZzuhmo40LGKoth2hwD3OI.kD0lYiIEwB1y\",\"created_at\":\"2021-07-20T08:34:19.350Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-07-20T08:34:19.350Z\",\"name\":\"Arden Stark\"}"
```

- with `puts`

```rb
2.6.0 (main):0 > puts User.first.to_json
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
{"id":1,"admin":true,"email":"admin@gmail.com","password_digest":"$2a$10$TQy3P7NT8KrdCzliNUsZzuhmo40LGKoth2hwD3OI.kD0lYiIEwB1y","created_at":"2021-07-20T08:34:19.350Z","updated_at":"2021-07-20T08:34:19.350Z","name":"Arden Stark"}
=> nil
```

#### if you are handle the json data, [JSON.pretty_generate](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E3/json#method-i-pretty_generate) is a good alternative

Example:

```rb
obj = {foo: [:bar, :baz], bat: {bam: 0, bad: 1}}
json = JSON.pretty_generate(obj)
puts json
```

Output:

```rb
{
  "foo": [
    "bar",
    "baz"
  ],
  "bat": {
    "bam": 0,
    "bad": 1
  }
}
```

#### if it's in the ROR project, I always prefer to use gem `pry-rails` to format my codes in the `rails console` rather than `awesome_print` which is too verbose.

Example of `pry-rails`:

[image]

it also has syntax highlight.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to quickly implement this in a Rails controller action to send a JSON response:

```
def index
  my_json = '{ "key": "value" }'
  render json: JSON.pretty_generate( JSON.parse my_json )
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution which I derived from other posts during my own search.

This allows you to send the pp and jj output to a file as needed.

```
require "pp"
require "json"

class File
  def pp(*objs)
    objs.each {|obj|
      PP.pp(obj, self)
    }
    objs.size <= 1 ? objs.first : objs
  end
  def jj(*objs)
    objs.each {|obj|
      obj = JSON.parse(obj.to_json)
      self.puts JSON.pretty_generate(obj)
    }
    objs.size <= 1 ? objs.first : objs
  end
end

test_object = { :name => { first: "Christopher", last: "Mullins" }, :grades => [ "English" => "B+", "Algebra" => "A+" ] }

test_json_object = JSON.parse(test_object.to_json)

File.open("log/object_dump.txt", "w") do |file|
  file.pp(test_object)
end

File.open("log/json_dump.txt", "w") do |file|
  file.jj(test_json_object)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used the gem CodeRay and it works pretty well. The format includes colors and it recognises a lot of different formats.

I have used it on a gem that can be used for debugging rails APIs and it works pretty well.

By the way, the gem is named 'api_explorer' (http://www.github.com/toptierlabs/api_explorer)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty print variant (**Rails**):

```rb
my_obj = {
  'array' => [1, 2, 3, { "sample" => "hash"}, 44455, 677778, nil ],
  foo: "bar", rrr: {"pid": 63, "state with nil and \"nil\"": false},
  wwww: 'w' * 74
}
```

```rb
require 'pp'
puts my_obj.as_json.pretty_inspect.
            gsub('=>', ': ').
            gsub(/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|\bnil\b/) {|m| m == 'nil' ? 'null' : m }.
            gsub(/\s+$/, "")
```

Result:

```json
{"array": [1, 2, 3, {"sample": "hash"}, 44455, 677778, null],
 "foo": "bar",
 "rrr": {"pid": 63, "state with nil and \"nil\"": false},
 "wwww":
  "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# example of use:
a_hash = {user_info: {type: "query_service", e_mail: "my@email.com", phone: "+79876543322"}, cars_makers: ["bmw", "mitsubishi"], car_models: [bmw: {model: "1er", year_mfc: 2006}, mitsubishi: {model: "pajero", year_mfc: 1997}]}
pretty_html = a_hash.pretty_html

# include this module to your libs:
module MyPrettyPrint
    def pretty_html indent = 0
        result = ""
        if self.class == Hash
            self.each do |key, value|
                result += "#{key}: #{[Array, Hash].include?(value.class) ? value.pretty_html(indent+1) : value}"
            end
        elsif self.class == Array
            result = "[#{self.join(', ')}]"
        end
        "#{result}"
    end

end

class Hash
    include MyPrettyPrint
end

class Array
    include MyPrettyPrint
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest example, I could think of:

```
my_json = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(my_json))
```

Rails console example:

```
core dev 1555:0> my_json = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }'
=> "{ \"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"car\":null }"
core dev 1556:0> puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(my_json))
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "car": null
}
=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) you can configure it as described [here](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/301) to use JSON.pretty_generate:

```
class PrettyJson
  def self.dump(object)
    JSON.pretty_generate(object, {:indent => "  "})
  end
end

Rabl.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.json_engine = PrettyJson if Rails.env.development?
  ...
end
```

A problem with using JSON.pretty_generate is that JSON schema validators will no longer be happy with your datetime strings. You can fix those in your config/initializers/rabl_config.rb with:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.class_eval do
  alias_method :orig_to_s, :to_s
  def to_s(format = :default)
    format == :default ? iso8601 : orig_to_s(format)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following as I find the headers, status and JSON output useful as
a set. The call routine is broken out on recommendation from a railscasts presentation at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?autoplay=true

```
  class LogJson

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    dup._call(env)
  end

  def _call(env)
    @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
    [@status, @headers, self]
  end

  def each(&block)
    if @headers["Content-Type"] =~ /^application\/json/
      obj = JSON.parse(@response.body)
      pretty_str = JSON.pretty_unparse(obj)
      @headers["Content-Length"] = Rack::Utils.bytesize(pretty_str).to_s
      Rails.logger.info ("HTTP Headers:  #{ @headers } ")
      Rails.logger.info ("HTTP Status:  #{ @status } ")
      Rails.logger.info ("JSON Response:  #{ pretty_str} ")
    end

    @response.each(&block)
  end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a JSON object in the rails console, and wanted to display it nicely in the console (as opposed to displaying like a massive concatenated string), it was as simple as:

```rb
data.as_json
```

Comment: I arrived back at my own answer (again after trying all the others) 6 months later. The mistake I was making a lot of was using `.to_json` instead of `.as_json`.