# Rails: JSON.pretty_generate(obj) in the controller does not produce pretty output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need a pretty output of the JSON for an activerecord object in the rails controller. Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails) by jpatokal, I tried the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => JSON.pretty_generate(record) }
end
```

where

```
record
```

is an activerecord object. It does not produce a prettified output. However, when I try outputting a hash using the same code, viz,

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => JSON.pretty_generate({"abc" => "1", "def" => "2"}) }
end
```

it does produce a prettified output (so pretty_generate is working, and so is my browser).

How do I use pretty_generate to produce a pretty output of an activerecord object?

Comment: presuming you explicity added `gem install json` to your Gemfile?

Comment: I didn't. However, it is there:
    $ gem list | grep "json"
    json (1.7.5)
    multi_json (1.3.6)

Comment: my suggestion is to try in rails console next, and exclude the format.json code.  basically see if `> JSON.pretty_generate(record)` exhibits the \n chars.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. In the console, record.to_json produces the json for the object. However,
`> JSON.pretty_generate(record)` gives the following error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'key?' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x007fa070fb6540>`. It appears that record cannot be serialized correctly?

Comment: sounds like the instance is a complex object, not easily serlialized. try some other json parser like `gem yajl-ruby`

Comment: before that, maybe even try `JSON.pretty_generate(record.as_json)` and/or `JSON.pretty_generate(record.to_json)` in console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get pretty output of JSON from an active record object you have to first request the object as JSON.

```
record.as_json
```

The above code will do this for you, the short way to render out pretty JSON from the controller is:

```
render json: JSON.pretty_generate(record.as_json)
```

This also solves the `"only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed"` error you can get trying to convert AR objects to `pretty_generate` JSON.

---

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention this can all be done in `rails 4.1.8` and above (possibly even earlier) using the standard `json` and `multi-json` gems packaged with rails project.