# Pretty print a JSON object created in Ruby to Chrome browser console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm parsing a Ruby object into JSON, rendering it in a js.erb file, and printing it to console (Chrome Browser).

In my js.erb file, when I print this:

```
console.log("<%= @search.attributes.to_json %>")
```

I get this:

```
{&quot;id&quot;:124,&quot;period_start&quot;:null,&quot;period_end&quot;:null,&quot;user_id&quot;:null,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2015-01-04T05:54:05.133Z&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2015-01-04T05:54:05.133Z&quot;,&quot;onscreen_people_rank_lower&quot;:null,&quot;onscreen_people_rank_upper&quot;:null,&quot;incl_onscreen_people_unranked&quot;:null,&quot;offscreen_people_rank_lower&quot;:null,&quot;offscreen_people_rank_upper&quot;:null,&quot;incl_offscreen_people_unranked&quot;:null}
```

which is very hard to read.  I want to make the JSON pretty so that I can read it more easily.

In my js.erb file, I've tried this:

```
console.log(eval("(" + "<%= @search.attributes.to_json %>" + ")"))
```

and this:

```
console.log( jQuery.parseJSON("<%= @search.attributes.to_json %>") )
```

and this:

```
console.log( "<%= JSON.pretty_generate(@search.attributes) %>" )
```

but none work--the code is not evaluated and nothing is outputted.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [Cba Bhusal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4073096/cba-bhusal)'s answer, this worked for me the best:

```
console.log("<%= j JSON.pretty_generate(@search.attributes).html_safe %>");
```

The `escape_javascript` was needed to escape quotes, while the `JSON.pretty_generate` inserted whitespace to make it even prettier.  The output in Chrome console looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 138,
  "user_id": null,
  "created_at": "2015-01-04T15:57:23.110Z",
  "updated_at": "2015-01-04T15:57:23.110Z"
  #...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its pretty simple, try this

```
console.log("<%= @search.attributes.to_json.html_safe %>")
```

Comment: thanks. for some reason, that didn't work, but this did: `console.log("<%= j @search.attributes.to_json.html_safe %>")`(added j)