# Pretty format my JSON output in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using pretty_generate in my controller, but I am getting the following error

'only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed'

```
@celebrities = Celebrity.includes(:category)    
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: JSON.pretty_generate(@celebrities.to_json(:include =>{:category => {:only => [:category]} })) }
end
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error

Comment: Step through it in the console, eg do `@celebrities.to_json(:include =>{:category => {:only => [:category]} })`, store the result in a variable, call `JSON.pretty_generate` on it etc.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Same error, do I need to add require json somewhere

Comment: Possibly, try `require 'json'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I "Pretty" format my JSON output in Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggest, `only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed`. I guess you should try this.

```
@celebrities = Celebrity.includes(:category)    
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(@celebrities.to_json(:include =>{:category => {:only => [:category]} })))}
end
```