# how to create a custom json from raw data (database data)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have create a show method in tour controller and want to render the data from the database into json format.
This the definition of the tour controller

```
class ToursController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :json

        def show    
            @tourcategory = Tourcategory.find(params[:id])
            @tours= @tourcategory.tours
            @tourcategories = Tourcategory.all
            render :layout => false

        end
    end
```

This is the definition of the show.html.haml view

```
    %h3 Tour for #{@tourcategory.title}
    = @tours.to_json
```

The output of this code is following:

```
[{"content":"dscfds","created_at":"2015-12-12T09:48:32Z","elementid":"test1","id":8,"jobid":2,"next_button_title":"next","priority":23,"title":"test1","updated_at":"2015-12-12T09:48:32Z"}]
```

But i just want to render the data in this kind of json format, following:

```
var tour = {
  id: "tour",
  steps: [
    {
      title: "abc",
      content: "Click this  Button.",
      target: "#abc",
      placement: "bottom",
      showNextButton: false,
      skipIfNoElement : true
    },
```

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: actually i want to give array structure to the output which is in  json

Comment: where does the `steps` array come from? I can't really see the relation between the two structures, please show more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve but it seems to me that you want to extract certain attributes from your `@tours` and group them as an array, if that's the case you can do something like this:

(list all the attributes you want inside `t.attributes.slice()`)

```
tour = { id: "tour", steps: @tours.map { |t| t.attributes.slice("title", "content", "target") } }
```

and if you want to convert your keys from snake (underscore) to camel format:

```
tour = {
        id: "tour",
        steps: @tours.map {|t| t.attributes.slice("title", "content").map {|k,v| [k.camelize(:lower), v]}.to_h} 
       }
```

Comment: This just defines a variable, put it inside your controller's action (if you want to use it in your view, you'll have to make it an instance variable `@tour`) and then simply render it in your view like you did previously or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: i have add this in my controller show method and do render on the show.html.haml view  but it gives an error undefined method 'map'