# Active Model Serializer formatting JSON display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, active-model-serializers

I am using Active model serializer in my rails app and I want to refactor the display:

Whenever I go to http://localhost:3000/api/users/1 I see:

```
{"data":{"id":"1","type":"users","attributes":{"username":"Iggy1"},"relationships":{"items":{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"items"},{"id":"7","type":"items"}]},"lists":{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"lists"},{"id":"8","type":"lists"},{"id":"14","type":"lists"},{"id":"15","type":"lists"},{"id":"17","type":"lists"}]}}}}
```

How can I make it to look like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "username": "Iggy1"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "items": {
                "data": [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "items"
                }, {
                    "id": "7",
                    "type": "items"
                }]
            },
            "lists": {
                "data": [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "lists"
                }, {
                    "id": "8",
                    "type": "lists"
                }, {
                    "id": "14",
                    "type": "lists"
                }, {
                    "id": "15",
                    "type": "lists"
                }, {
                    "id": "17",
                    "type": "lists"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have spent a good amount of time browsing through [adapters](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/adapters.md), [rendering](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/rendering.md#overriding-the-root-key), [architecture](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/ARCHITECTURE.md), but I couldn't find the guide. First off, is it possible to make it look like the second code block above? Second, if it is possible, what must I do to change the display?

**api/users_controller.rb**

```
   def show
     @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
     @no_user_found = User.all #other alternative when user ID not found?
     if @user.nil?
       flash[:notice] = "No user found"
       render json: @no_user_found, each_serializer: UserSerializer
     else
      render json: @user, each_serializer: UserSerializer
    end
   end
```

**user_serializer.rb**

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :username#, :email
   has_many :items, through: :lists
   has_many :lists
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do

     resources :users do
       resources :lists
     end

     resources :lists, only: [] do
       resources :items, only: [:create, :index, :show, :update]
     end

     resources :items, only: [:destroy]
   end
end
```

Comment: Just clarifying, is your question is how to make one liner output to and output of json with line indention?

Comment: Currently it is displaying a one-liner. I wanted to "fix" the display to include indentations and new line characters.

Comment: I guess you are displaying it on browser. Why don't you use [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: I will look into Postman; I have heard of that before :) And yes, I am viewing it from browser; is it possible to include the indentation and new line from the browser?

Comment: I added answer below.

Comment: You can render it in browser take a look at my answer below.

Comment: Use `JSON.pretty_generate(json)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using browser, I suggest to use [Postman](http://Postman)
`pretty_generate`.

You can render it with indentions and newline using the following below code:

```
<pre><%= JSON.pretty_generate(your_json_here) %></pre>
```

In your code above do it with:

```
<%
  require 'json'

  hash = JSON[{"data":{"id":"1","type":"users","attributes":{"username":"Iggy1"},"relationships":{"items":{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"items"},{"id":"7","type":"items"}]},"lists":{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"lists"},{"id":"8","type":"lists"},{"id":"14","type":"lists"},{"id":"15","type":"lists"},{"id":"17","type":"lists"}]}}}}.to_json] 
%>

<pre>
  <%=  JSON.pretty_generate(hash)%>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about styling the json output.  As @araratan suggested above you can use  to only make readable for you. And there no necessary to make stylish to use in machine.
if you need the same look in th[Generate preety json outpur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: He can style it adding `<pre>` html code. See my answer below.