# Display formatted JSON in HTML without JavaScript (Ruby, Sinatra)

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra, geojson

I'm building a practice Web API with Ruby + Sinatra and I want my responses to be displayed in a ERB template with formatted JSON (GeoJSON). So far I've been able to process the request and format the response correctly.

However, I can't find a way to display the contents in the endpoint as a JSON string, and it displays as a regular string (difficult to read for JSON). Is there any way to do that in Ruby + Sinatra without using JavaScript?

Here's what I've got so far in both files.

```rb
# app.rb

before do
    json = File.open("data/cities.json").read
    data = JSON.parse(json)
    data.each do |item|
        geoarray["features"].append(json_to_geojson(item))
    end
    @geojson = geoarray.to_json
end

...

get('/myendpoint') do
    @activities = @geojson
    erb :cities
end
```

```html
<!--cities.erb-->

<%= @activities %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<%= @activities.to_json.html_safe %>`

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work. Is html_safe for Sinatra or Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You can make JSON string look prettier by using `JSON.pretty_generate()` method.

```rb
# app.rb
before do
    json = File.open("data/cities.json").read
    data = JSON.parse(json)
    data.each do |item|
        geoarray["features"].append(json_to_geojson(item))
    end

    # use pretty_generate instead of to_json 
    @geojson = JSON.pretty_generate(geoarray)
end
```

And In your erb file. Instead of simple showing it, add `<pre>` tag to it.

```rb
<!--cities.erb-->

<pre><%= @activities %></pre>
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-to-pretty-format-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails#answer-17455728)